# Why is the word "whatnot" a construction of "what" and "not"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've done some online etymological research on the word "whatnot", but I've been unable to figure out why it is a construction of "what" and "not".

How does the combination of the words "what" and "not" relate to the meaning of "whatnot" (simply, *anything*)?

Comment: [Basic research](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=whatnot) obviates this question.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica To be fair, I asked this question over 10 years ago. I'm fairly certain I was aware of the linked website back then - and I most likely used it for my primary research. 

The recent (20 days ago) private feedback is well-received - to include the research I have already done before posting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think of it as a contraction of "what[ever was] not [mentioned]" - i.e., everything else. I don't know whether that's etymologically correct, though.

Comment: Exactly, but I think it would have been something more like "and what not to [include]" (a variant without the *ever*). In any case, what we have here is a failure to imaginate -- even though we leave things out of our conversations all of the time and live in a world that abbreviates nearly everything, we sometimes manage to forget that other people have left things out for convenience in the past as well. Sometimes things just stay left out.

Answer (score 3):

*Whatnot* was originally a placeholder name like *whatsit* or *thingamabob* for miscellaneous trifling items.  It is just something that did not have an obvious name.

It later became a word describing furniture for holding such things, typically a small stack of corner shelves.  [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=whatnot) gives 1530s for the first use and 1808 for the second.

Comment: Yep, saw all that stuff. Still not quite an answer to my question though. I understand how whatsit is related (what is it), but whatnot still stumps me.

Comment: @Chris Dwyer As you have done some research already, you may include all that in your question.

Comment: @Dante I didn't see it as necessary for someone to sufficiently answer the question... which was why the two words (what and not) combine to mean what "whatnot" means. Obviously, my research didn't come up with an answer to this question. Henry didn't answer the question at all, but skirted around it by merely defining it and citing its first recorded use.

Comment: @Chris Dwyer: I was trying to be helpful.  If you look at Google images for a *whatnot* then you will see the furniture (and Muppets). The name for the funiture comes from the miscellaneous items displayed on it (so that is its etymology).  The placeholder name for the items themselves doesn't seem to have any more of an etymology than *thingamebob* does. It is just some words/sounds strung together for something not given a useful description.

Comment: That's fine. Perhaps your post would've been better as a comment instead of an answer? Also, if you think that there is no etymological reason for "what" and "not" coming together to mean what "whatnot" means, then that should be your answer. No worries though - no downvote... but no upvote either. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had always assumed that *whatnot* is an abbreviation of sorts for a exclamation like "My, what *isn't* on that list!"

Answer (score 0):

Whatnot strikes me a a respelling of the King James Biblical expression "wot not," meaning "don't know" as in "we wot not what is become of him" --Acts 7:40. Of course, that was a verb form, transitioned to noun. So a whatnot is like "whatchamajigger" - a fun alternative to "thing." I know this is a response to an old post, but inquiring minds still want to know.

Comment: Your answer would be stronger if it included corroboration from a reference work. As matters stand, the answer seems pretty conjectural.